# PhantomJS caching. Where it is stored?

Tags: caching, phantomjs

I am using PhantomJS to parse some sites. Given a URL, I parse it and then I start other instances to parse related URLs (same host/domain).  I see that the time of loading the page is quite big, so I was digging into the --disk-cache option.

My question is:

Where is that cache stored? I am launching my PhantomJS instances from a Rails app in Heroku, and I would like to know where is that cache stored (which directory).

Answer (score 8):

Check on below path :
Linux : ~/.qws/cache/Ofi Labs/PhantomJS

Windows : AppData\Local\Ofi Labs\PhantomJS\cache

Files with extension **'.d'** have the cached items.

Comment: FreeBSD: $HOME/.cache/Ofi Labs/PhantomJS/*/*/*.d

Comment: this stuff not working anymore, phantomjs uses sqlite to save cache in database file .localstorage

Comment: CentOS/RHEL: `~/.local/share/Ofi Labs/PhantomJS` or if running in a container `/root/.local/share/Ofi Labs/PhantomJS`

Comment: In my container, on Alpine it was in `/root/.local/share/Ofi\ Labs/PhantomJS`

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS X, the default path is `~/Library/Caches/Ofi Labs/PhantomJS`.

Answer (score 1):

The linux path is now usually
`~/.local/share/Ofi\ Labs/PhantomJS/`