# How could I save all resources received into disk in phantomjs?

Tags: phantomjs

I want to use page.onResourceReceived event handler in phantomjs to save all resources received into disk, how could I accomplish this? Are there any methods to save all resources received into disk in phantomjs?

I think This question is not related to cache: if use cache, then how to parse the cached files and extract their data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PhantomJS caching. Where it is stored?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24192058/phantomjs-caching-where-it-is-stored)

Comment: it is a different question!

Comment: Yes, it's a different question, but it contains all information to answer yours.

Comment: The resources saved should be enumerated and read again. If use cache, how to enumerate and read each resource again? how to parse the cached files and extract their data?

Comment: Well, that's not what you're asking here. But sure, you can parse the cached files and extract their data if you like.